# how to check a YouTube video exist in the directory or not by providing the link of the video using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

**How to write a program, Suppose you are downloading a YouTube playlist which contains some number of videos but due to some network issue downloading got failed and a few videos downloaded and few not so how to write a program that will check whether the video exists in the directory if it is then it will skip if not then download the video?**

```
import os
from pytube import YouTube, Playlist
from pytube.cli import on_progress

def Downloader(str):
    url = YouTube(str, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
    video = url.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    video.download('D:\YouTube\Yash Raj Mukhate')   # Here we give the download location
    print('\nDownloaded successfully')


link = input('Please Give the link: ')
playlist = Playlist(link)
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))
for video_url in playlist.video_urls:
    video_name = YouTube(video_url).title
    if os.path.exists(f'D:\YouTube\Yash Raj Mukhate{video_name}.mp4'):
        print('File Exist')
    else:
        print('File does not exist)
```

Comment: can anyone help me Please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to write a program, Suppose you are downloading a YouTube playlist which contains some number of videos but due to some network issue downloading got failed and a few videos downloaded and few not so how to write a program that will check whether the video exists in the directory if it is then it will skip if not then download the video?

Comment: Suppose the playlist contains 40 videos and 5 videos downloaded and the remaining not downloaded. If we check one by one then it will take time so how to write a program that will check whether the video exists in the directory if it is then it will skip if not then download the video. In the sample code, I was trying to check whether the video exists or not.